# Tips to write thread-safe UNIX code?

Tags: c, unix, multithreading, thread-safety

What are the guidelines to write thread-safe UNIX code in C and C++?

I know only a few:

- Don't use globals
- Don't use static local storage

What others are there?

Comment: Please mark poll questions 'community wiki'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple thing to do is read a little.  The following list contains some stuff to look at and research.

1. Spend time reading the [Open Group Base Specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) particularly the [General Information](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html) section and the [subsection on threads](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09).  This is the basis information for multithreading under most UN*X-alike systems.
2. Learn the [difference between a mutex and a semaphore](http://koti.mbnet.fi/niclasw/MutexSemaphore.html)
3. Realize that everything that is shared *MUST* be protected.  This applies to global variables, `static` variables, and any shared dynamically allocated memory.
4. Replace global state flags with [condition variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_variables).  These are implemented using [`pthread_cond_init`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_destroy.html) and related functions.

Once you understand  the basics, learn about the common problems so that you can identify them *when* they occur:

- [Lock inversion deadlocks](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/acquiring-multiple-locks-without-deadlock.html)
- [Priority inversion](http://www.embedded.com/story/OEG20020321S0023) - if you are interested in a real life scenario, then [read this snippet about the Mars Pathfinder](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/mbj/mars_pathfinder/mars_pathfinder.html)

Comment: Wow, i basically hadn't heard about anything that you listed here! Starting to read.

Comment: There is a lot of information out there.  If you want more booklike things, give the notes at https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/ a read or buy "UNIX Systems Programming" (http://www.amazon.com/UNIX-Systems-Programming-Communication-Concurrency/dp/0130424110/)

Answer (score 2):

It really comes down to shared state, globals and static local are examples of shared state.  If you don't share state, you won't have a problem.  Other examples of shared state include  multiple threads writing to a file or socket.

*Any* shared resource will need to be managed properly - that might mean making something mutex protected, opening another file, or intelligently serializing requests.

If two threads are reading and writing from the same struct, you'll need to handle that case.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of the `sem_t` functions, they may return uncompleted on interrupts, IO, SIGCHLD etc. If you need them, be sure to *allways* capture that case.

`pthread_mut_t` and `pthread_cond_t` functions are safe with respect to `EINTR`.

Answer (score 0):

A good open book about concurrency in general can be found here: [Little Book of Semaphores](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/)

It presents various problems that are solved step-by step and include solutions to common concurrency issues like starvation, race conditions etc.
It is not language-specific but contains short chapters about implementing the solutions in C with the Pthread-Library or Python.